# Tabularize and align equations after bullet itemize

Tags: align

Here's some code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$]
    \item Example1
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}$A \cap (B \cap C)=(A \cap B)\cap C$ \\ $A \cup (B \cup C)=(A \cup B)\cup C$\end{tabular}
        \end{tabular}
    \item Example2
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}$A \cap (A\cup B) = A$ \\ $A \cup (A\cap B) = A$\end{tabular}
        \end{tabular}
    \item Example3
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}$A \cap (B \cup C)=(A \cap B)\cup (A \cap B)$ \\ $A \cup (B \cap C)=(A \cup B)\cap (A \cup B)$\end{tabular}
        \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

But the output I get is:

[image]

How can I drag these equations to the right but also make them aligned at equal sign? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) (1) Please make your code compilable. Right now `enumitem` is not loaded, `label=\bullet` will cause an error anyway, and you have `\emd{document}` instead of `\end{document}`. (2) Please explan what "_drag to the right_" exactly means. Should the equations be centered as if they were displayed equations?

Comment: @campa let me fix that quickly. Yes, I want them to be centered.

Comment: Please change `[label=\bullet]` to either `[label=$\bullet$]` or, better still, `[label=\textbullet]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A (AFAIK not very well known) nice feature of `\intertext` is that you can put something like `\item` inside it; only the first `\item` must be outside the `align` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,mathtools}
    
% Just to see the baseline
\newcommand*{\foo}{\rlap{\vrule width 5cm height 0pt depth 0.2pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
\abovedisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\item Example1\foo
\begin{align*}
A \cap (B \cap C) &=(A \cap B)\cap C \\
A \cup (B \cup C) &=(A \cup B)\cup C
\intertext{\item Example2\foo}
A \cap (A \cup B) &= A \\
A \cup (A \cap B) &= A
\intertext{\item Example3\foo}
A \cap (B \cup C) &= (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B) \\
A \cup (B \cap C) &= (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup B)
\end{align*}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to have the baseline of the formula to align with the baseline of the `\item` I set `\abovedisplayskip` equal to `-\baselineskip`. For this to work also after the various occurrences of `\intertext` we need however the `mathtools` package, an extension to `amsmath` which does change a bit the definition of `\intertext`. Without `mathtools` (i.e. with `amsmath` only) the result would be

[image]

Comment: amazing! Thanks a lot!!